# rename file by adding an incrementing number to old file name c#

Tags: c#, cocoa, file-rename

I'm writing my first Cocoa app in c#, its suppose to append/add numbers at the begging of a file name.

Users give only the path to the folder (for example with music), and for each file included in folder the program suppose to add incrementing numbers like

```
001_(old_fileName),
002_(old_fileName), 
..., 
092_(old_fileName)
etc,
```

Untill the end of files in given folder (by path).

There is no way to split a file name, cause file names are not known (may even include numbers itself). I've tried few possible options to solve this, but non of them works. Found few already asked question with changing names in c# but non of the results actually helped me.

The code under is the rest I've got at the moment, all non-working tries were firstly commented and later deleted. by NSAlert i see the path/name of each file in folder as a help. I would be more than happy to receive help

```
void RenameFunction()
{
   string sPath = _Path_textBox.StringValue;

   if (Directory.Exists(sPath))
   {
      var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sPath);
      var txt2Files = Directory.GetFiles((sPath));


      string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sPath);
      string extension = Path.GetExtension(sPath);
      string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath);
      string newFullPath = sPath;
      int count = 1;


      while (File.Exists(sPath))//newFullPath))
      {
         string tempFileName = string.Format(count + "_" + fileNameOnly + sPath);
         //count++;
         //string.Format("{0}{0}{0}{1}", fileNameOnly, count++);
         newFullPath = Path.Combine(path, extension + tempFileName);
         count++;
      }

      string[] fileEntities = Directory.GetFiles(newFullPath);  //GetFileSystemEntries(sPath);//GetFiles(sPath);   
      //foreach (var _songName in fileEntities)
      //{
      //    string tempFileName = count + "_" + fileNameOnly + sPath;
      //            //string.Format("{0}{0}{0}{1}", fileNameOnly, count++);
      //        newFullPath = Path.Combine(sPath ,extension + tempFileName);
      //    File.Move(sPath, newFullPath);
      //}
      foreach (var _songName in fileEntities)
      {

         AmountofFiles(_songName);
      }
   }
}

void AmountofFiles(string path)
{
   var alert2 = new NSAlert();
   alert2.MessageText = "mp3";
   alert2.InformativeText = "AMOUNT OF MP3 FILES IS '{1}' : " + path;
   alert2.RunModal();
}
```

Comment: In your code you are only using `spath` to do file operations. `spath` is directory path. I don't see anywhere in your code which does anything with any of the file inside the directory. Why not use `txtFiles` variable to iterate thru the files of directory and rename them?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya do you mean:
 

    `foreach (var _file in txtFiles)
                    {
                        string _bufor = count.ToString() + fileNameOnly;
                        File.Move(sPath, _bufor);
                    }` 

?? sorry i cant format it right as a code :/

Comment: Did you try this approach? You don't need to use fileNameOnly variable here. What issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya ok, right now i have a problem, that lets say I'm "inside" folder in which i want to change files names. the problem I'm facing is how to change name i don't know. `File.Move()` exception is saying that file name as given path is not existing and its true, so how to get it

Comment: I posted the answer below. Please follow it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks a lot for your help! I've messed up the place of `Path.GetFileName`

Answer (score 0):

Have you try use File.Move? Just move file to same path, but another name

```
File.Move("NameToBeRename.jpg","NewName.jpg");
```

Comment: i was trying File.Move but maybe I've putted it in the wrong place in code. I'll see if it works with advice of Chetan

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things which are not right with the code you share. The thing which want to achieve can be implemented using very simple approach.

All you need to do is retrieve all the files names with the full path from the directory and rename them one by one.

Follow the below code which demonstrates the above mentioned approach.

```
// Path of the directory.
var directroy = _Path_textBox.StringValue;

if (Directory.Exists(directroy))
{
    //Get all the filenames with full path from the directory.
    var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directroy);

    //Variable to append number in front of the file name.
    var count = 1;

    //Iterate thru all the file names 
    foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
    {
        //Get only file name from the full file path.
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        //Create new path with the directory path and new file name.
        var destLocation = Path.Combine(directory, count + fileName);

        //User File.Move to move file to the same directory with new name.
        File.Move(filePath, destLocation);

        //Increment count.
        count++;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you to resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks, i actually did the almost the same later, but before your posted a comment, i messed up the place where i've have putted the `Path.GetFileName` Thanks a lot for you help!